# How do you get miners to mine for gems?

Tags: godus

When I build a new mining settlement and all the miners are unemployed, I can leash from the mining settlement to a gem seam. But after the miner is done on the gem seam, they build a mine and work on that. When I leash miners that are working on mines to gem seams, they turn around and go back to their mine after walking to the gem seam. If I use finger of god on a mine, the miner will just build a new mine. How do I consistently get miners to work on gem seams?